# Can only log in as "guest" after editing /etc/passwd to change UID to 0

Tags: sudo, users

To get superuser access my friend edited his `/etc/passwd` file, changing the UID and GID to `0`, because he read somewhere it should be same as root.

Then when he tried using commands with `sudo` he started getting a message `unknown user 1000 who are you`.

I myself haven't used much Linux. I tried editing GRUB parameters to enter as root but I couldn't edit the `passwd` file. I couldn't even add a new user because the `passwd` file couldn't be written into.

Now when he chooses Ubuntu in the GRUB menu he only gets the option of a guest login. How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start the computer and press <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> to enter the grub menu and choose **Advanced Options for Ubuntu**:

[image: Choose Advanced Options]

In the following menu choose **Ubuntu, with Linux xx.xx.x-xx-generic (recovery mode)**:

> Note: I placed here small x for the kernel version numbers so don't get confused, on my system, since it is 17.10 it is 4.13.0-16 but on your system this may differ.

[image: Choose Recovery Mode]

The system will then boot up into the following screen where you should choose **enable networking** to begin with. It prompts you that it needs to remount the file-system in read-and-write mode, you need to allow this.

> Note: This step is easier as remounting the drive into read-write from command line

[image: Enable Networking]

You will be returned to this selection after that. Now you can choose to go into a **root shell**. Press <kbd>Return</kbd> once to be finally in as root on a writable file-system.

Now enter the following:

```
cd /etc
nano passwd
```

Inside the editor navigate to the last line and revert the change. The line should look something like this:

```
username:x:1000:1000:username,,,:/home/username:/bin/bash
```

Where `username` is your username.

After you have made your changes press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit the program, you are then asked to confirm that you want to write, which you should do by pressing <kbd>y</kbd> and finally you are asked for a name to save to. There you don't need to change anything, just press <kbd>Return</kbd>.

As final command enter:

```
reboot
```

And this should solve your problem. Have fun!

Note: Ah and before I forget, tell your friend to keep his fingers out of the system unless he really knows what he is doing. :)

Comment: @AbhigyanNagraj if this answer solves your problem, do not forget to accept it by clicking that small checkmark beside it. This way it wont live here on the Site as unanswered.